# preventDefault does not work with modal window

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a modal window that can be closed by clicking on either ouside the modal window itself or by clicking on a close button

```
const onCloseHandler = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setIsModalOpen(false);
};

return (
    <div className="overlay" onClick={onCloseHandler}>
        <div className="modal-window">
            <div type="button" className="close-button" onClick={onCloseHandler}>
                <CloseIcon />
            </div>

            <img src={image} alt="task" className="modal-image" />
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

The problem is `preventDefault` does not work so the modal window closes even if I click on an image or div with `modal-window` class.

I tried to use

```
const onCloseHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        return;
    }

    setIsModalOpen(false);
};
```

And it works but it does not seem like a good solution. And also it does not close the modal window when click on a CloseIcon. It is just an svg inside so it's not possible to use `pointer-events: none` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner solution might be moving `modal-window` out of `overlay`.

This way, `modal-window` is independent to `overlay`. Although it can be styled to be stacking on top of it, because `overlay` is not a parent of `modal-window`, clicking on `modal-window` will not trigger the event on `overlay`.

```
<>
<div className="overlay" onClick="{onCloseHandler}"></div>

<div className="modal-window">
  <div type="button" className="close-button" onClick="{onCloseHandler}">
    <CloseIcon />
  </div>
  <img src="{image}" alt="task" className="modal-image" />
</div>
</>
```

Alternatively, do a condition check on `e.target` based on some attributes could also work. This way does not require restructuring of the elements.

```
const onCloseHandler = (e) => {
  if (e.target.className === "modal-window") return;
  setIsModalOpen(false);
};
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: but how would moving overlay to another component fix this? What actually changes in event bubbling? Could you please explain this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `stopPropagation` on your `modal-window` element.

Remember that clicking is going to start at the most deeply nested element, and then (by default) propagate/bubble up through all higher level elements.

And so of course, in your current solution, of course, given that `modal-window` is inside `overlay`,  clicking anything inside `modal-window` also ends up counting as a click on `overlay`.

So you could make it so that `overlay` is not the parent of `modal-window`, à la John Li's answer.

Or, if you retain the existing structure, the click events would be:

```
`overlay` -> Close the modal 
`modal-window` -> stopPropagation, do nothing. 
`close-button` -> Close the modal, allow propagation (propagation will stop at `modal-window`)
```